# edit/set application.caller in vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have a userdefined array-function which makes use of application.caller to determine the number of rows from which the function is called.

Now i want to run the same function from vba. the Problem is that now the application.caller object doesn't include any information about the number of rows.

is there a way to call the function inside vba and manually set application.caller so that i can pass the number of rows as information?

there is one important contraint: i can not edit the function in any way, it has to be completely unchanged!

Comment: No you can't set `Application.Caller`.

Comment: This is too vague to really answer. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: If you can't edit the function you will have to drop it into a spreadsheet, evaluate it and then continue with the result while deleting your edit.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `TypeName(Application.Caller)` to see how the function was called and then set a row count based on that - but if you can't change the function then I'd say the answer is "no".

Comment: If you are writing VBA code (which you must be if you are trying to call this function from VBA) why not write a new version of the function, one that doesn't depend on `Application.Caller`? I doubt that this function is very well-written (the use of `Application.Caller` the way that you describe seems problematic). Why not just directly implement the functionality that you need rather than call a possibly poorly written function that you are not allowed to modify?